# Is there any way to fix hard coded databases name within my view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a view where I have currently used hard coded database names. But the problem with this approach is that for each and every server environment environment, I have to change the database name because the database names are not consistent across all the servers.

I am using `.dacpac` to deploy the database from one server to another but the problem is same the database names are inconsistent.

e.g. for some server database name is `PatientDemographics_Migration` but on some servers the name is `PatientDemographics_Migration_P` and the same applies to other database name used here in the script.

Is there anyway to fix this problem? I do not want to provide database name for every environment.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_migration_Demographics] 
AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        patdemo.NHI AS [NHI],
        demo.FamilyName AS [Surname],
        demo.FirstName AS [FirstName],
        demo.Prefix AS [Title],
        demo.Gender AS [Gender]
    FROM 
        [PatientDemographics_Migration].[dbo].[PatientDemographics] demo
    INNER JOIN 
        [Encounter_Migration].[dbo].PatientEncounter pe ON pe.NHI = demo.nhi
```

Comment: Is the view in the same database as the the name of the one in question? Then just don't use any database name in the view's definition.

Comment: Like @stickybit said, if the `VIEW` is created in the database the other objects are in then there is no need to use 3 part naming, just use 2 part naming. If not, then no, a `VIEW` cannot dynamically choose the database. You *could* however, create synonyms in the database that you alter to reference the correct database objects. If the names of the databases are inconsistent, however, it seems like the correct solution is to make them consistent.

Comment: @stickybit View is under `[Encounter_Migration]` database. As you can see, I am using 2 different databases to use 2 different tables.

Comment: @Larnu The database name across different servers are inconsistent. Can you please elaborate more on this. If possible then please provide some sample solution for this.

Comment: This is the result of a lack of planning. Someone specifically decided to divide the system's "data" between two (at least) databases. You now have the problem of supporting that architecture while also implementing multiple environments. Synonyms might be useful here in this particular situation but it might not work for every reference. You also have the self-inflicted (by the developer - is that you?) wound of using a 3 part name to reference tables in the same database as the one containing your view. Short answer is you need a more complex deployment process/tool.

Comment: Is your code in SSDT projects? You can use SQL CMD variables for external database names then set them as needed in your deployment pipeline

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes this is SSDT project. Appreciated if you could provide some solution to work around my problem.

Comment: First of all get rid of any three part names that refer to the current database. Then add a database reference with [Different database, same server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box?view=sql-server-ver15) for all external databases and ensure all code in the project is updated to use the SQL Cmd variable instead of a hardcoded name (e.g. `[$(SomeVariableName)]`). Then when publishing simply specify the desired name.

Comment: @MartinSmith, the problem here is that I am using `.dacpac` file to restore the database into another server. I am building the solution in one server and taking that `.dacpac` and restoring  it on another server where the database names are different. If I am running the view manually then your solution seems working but how about this situation. Please en light more on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "restore a dacpac"? Dacpacs are published/deployed not restored. If you generate a dacpac from the SSDT project you can then use that to deploy to all environments. You shouldn't be creating new dacpacs from existing environments because then it will lose things like the `sqlcmd` variables. Your deployment pipeline should save the dacpacs that were used for each release to a lower environment so the same dacpac can be used when you promote the release to a higher environment

Comment: @MartinSmith, sorry it's my bad. Yes it is deploy not restore. Let me explain in more details about my situation. I have SSIS solution where I am using a project. In that project, I have used View. In that View, I am using 2 different databases with name `PatientDemographics_Migration` and `Encounter_Migration`. To use `.dacpac`, I have to build the solution but as you have seen, the `.dacpac` contains these 2 databases. Now I have to take this `.dacpac` and deploy it on another server where the databases name are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one *real* solution here, as has been mentioned in the other answer: "fix" the names of the databases across your servers, make them consistently named. That means changing the name of the databases across the servers to be the same. Based on your question, that would be `PatientDemographics_Migration` and `Encounter_Migration`.

You can rename a database as detailed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15#rename-a-database-using-transact-sql):

> ```
> USE master;  
> GO  
> ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
> GO
> ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase MODIFY NAME = MyTestDatabaseCopy ;
> GO  
> ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabaseCopy SET MULTI_USER
> GO
> ```

Obviously replace `MyTestDatabase` and `MyTestDatabaseCopy` with the appropriate names.

Of course, as well, renaming your databases may break other code if you have used 3 part naming else where, so you will need to fix the definitions of those objects too, after you rename the database.

---

As I mention in my comment under the question, `VIEW` objects **cannot** dynamically reference objects. That have to be well defined, as reference specific objects, and can only contain a `SELECT` statement (CTEs are allowed, as these are expressions).

They can, however, use Synonyms, which *can* be helpful in these circumstances. These Synonyms would still need to be created, and defined specifically for each instance, however, your `VIEW`'s definition would then be static.

Firstly, you would create your `SYNONYM`:

```
USE {Database containing the VIEW};
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.PatientDemographics FOR [PatientDemographics_Migration].[dbo].[PatientDemographics];
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.PatientEncounter FOR [Encounter_Migration].[dbo].PatientEncounter;
GO
```

These synonyms would be different on **every** instance that has a different name for the database. So on one where you have the `_P` suffix it would be:

```
CREATE SYNONYM PatientDemographics FOR [PatientDemographics_Migration_P].[dbo].[PatientDemographics];
```

Then, once you've created the synonyms bespoke to the instance, in the database the `VIEW` is going to be created in, you can create the `VIEW` using a static definition, across all the instances:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_migration_Demographics] 
AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        patdemo.NHI AS [NHI],
        demo.FamilyName AS [Surname],
        demo.FirstName AS [FirstName],
        demo.Prefix AS [Title],
        demo.Gender AS [Gender]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[PatientDemographics] demo --Notice no 3 part naming as it references the synonym in the same database
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].PatientEncounter pe ON pe.NHI = demo.nhi; --Notice no 3 part naming as it references the synonym in the same database
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is inconsistent database naming nomenclature. Follow the Principle Of Least Astonishment -  In other words, the users should not be surprised, startled, or astonished by the system's behavior, or by the behavior of any of the system's components.

You should not be changing the database name in every environment. What you will end up is spending unnecessary time trying to code around this.

Standardize the naming of your databases and start using named instances if you need them for alternative environments etc. It should be an easy change to sell as the savings in time and effort will pay for themselves.

Comment: Database names are different on different servers like `_D' at the end of the database name denotes development environment. `_P` production and so on. So I am not sure how to fix this issue. I do not want to provide database name every time. I am using `.dacpac` to restore the database from one server to another.

Comment: You fix it by making the names consistent, @MVC .